# comparison logic in this if statement

Tags: java, oop, if-statement

I was wondering if you can explain to me this comparison logic:

```
public class Workplace {
    private int index = 0;
    private String name;
    private Employee[] employees;

    public Workplace(String name, int numberOfEmployees){
        this.name = name;
        this.employees = new Employee[numberOfEmployees];
    }

    public Employee[] returnEmployees(Employee e){
        Employee youngestEmployee = null;
        Employee oldestEmployee = null;

        for(int i=0; i<index; i++){
            if(youngestEmployee == null || employees[i].getAge() > youngestEmployee.getAge()){
                youngestEmployee = employees[i];
            }
            else if(oldestEmployee == null || employees[i].getAge() < oldestEmployee.getAge()){
                oldestEmployee = employees[i];
            }
        }
        return new Employee[] {youngestEmployee, oldestEmployee};
    }
}
```

In particular, the if statement comparison logic over here:

```
if(youngestEmployee == null || employees[i].getAge() > youngestEmployee.getAge()){
    youngestEmployee = employees[i];
}
else if(oldestEmployee == null || employees[i].getAge() < oldestEmployee.getAge()){
    oldestEmployee = employees[i];
}
```

I've got another class called Employee, in which I have declared the get and set methods. And have the **age** variable declared as an int.
So I know that this if statement comparison logic wants to get the youngest and oldest employee but I am getting confused at this part:

```
employees[i].getAge() > youngestEmployee.getAge()
```

Instead of saying less than, here it is greater than.
I couldn't find an answer yet.
Thank you for your time!

Comment: Why is index a field in the class? Isn't this supposed to be the amount of employees, so `employees.length`?

Comment: and where do you set `index`? In the code you showed us it is always `0`.

Comment: @Nico Van Belle You are right. I will use index in some later code. I will use the index to see if there's space left in the array (employees) when I want to add a new employee.

Comment: @Hulk I will manually add employees in the array later. I just wanted to understand the logic behind this if statement. If the index has to do something with it, please enlighten me! Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right to doubt on the code. The comparison looks wrong.

```
if(youngestEmployee == null || employees[i].getAge() > youngestEmployee.getAge()){
    youngestEmployee = employees[i];
}
```

This says: if the age of the current employee is **greater than** the youngest, set the current as the youngest.
It should be the contrary.

Comment: So instead of using greater than, I should use less than and I will be good? Since the 'youngestEmployee' and 'oldestEmployee' variables are null, can this always return me null? Thank you for your reply.

Comment: There are two cases that your code will return null values.
Case 1): your list of Employee is empty: in this case you never enter the for cycle, and the two variables oldestEmployee and youngestEmployee will stay null.

Comment: Case 2): the list of Employee contains only null values. One or more, like: [null, null, ..., null]. Actually, in this case your code would break at "employees[i].getAge()": you would get a NullPointerException for trying to access the field "age" of a null Employee. But if we assume you only put non-null employees in your list, the code would work.

Answer (score 0):

Lets suppose

this.employees = new Employee[5];
Employee youngestEmployee = null;

The logic here is that it's looping through a list of all employees(currently we have five employees) and takes the current employee meaning the employee at i(employees[i]) in that list of employees that you declared on the top and use a get method or a getter from your Employee class to get the age of that current employee from you employees array class and then compare it with the age of the previous employee(youngestEmployee). At first the youngestEmployee=null so it will set youngestEmployee=employees[i](suppose the value of employees[i]=25) but at the second time it will compare the age of the employee at i(employees[i]) and then compare it to the previous value(which was 25). Then it will decide the new value of youngestEmployee accoding to the result it got from the if statement.

Comment: So, at the null value the program will set the first employee age as the youngest, and then it will compare the others with that first value, or whichever value will be stored after comparison? If this is the case, so now should I change the greater than (>) to less than (<) because to me this seems wrong? Thank you for your time and reply!

Comment: You should compare the current value with the youngest. If the current is greater than the youngest then it means that the value of youngest won't change.